# Chrome browser on Windows 8 desktop: touch support error

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8, touch

Chrome browser (version 23.0.1271.97) on Windows 8 desktop is erroneously recognized as supporting touch events. Actually it is a desktop, that is to say, it doesn't support touch events.

See for example Modernizr Touch tests: http://modernizr.github.com/Modernizr/touch.html

Did anybody run into this problem?
Is there a solution or a workaround?

Comment: Ah, but the browser *does* support touch events. It wouldn't stop supporting mouse events if you unplugged a mouse. What's the problem you are trying to solve? Are you asking for ways to detect whether you should show a touch friendly site?

Comment: per http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=152149 the behavior I'm seeing in 23.0.1271.97 is correct (namely, only typeof TouchEvent != "undefined" shows Yes)

Comment: @rikkit yes, this the problem I try to solve. I use javascript-based approaches/tests to detect touch support in the browser. You can see the tests at [http://modernizr.github.com/Modernizr/touch.html](http://modernizr.github.com/Modernizr/touch.html). For example, Chrome 23 on Win Vista and on Mac passes the tests correctly. Chrome   23 on Win 8 desktop returns wrong results.

Comment: @JimO'Neil my experience is that Chrome 23 on Win 8 returns wrong results: typeof Touch == "object" test shows No, other tests show Yes. For example, Chrome 23 on Mac and Win Vista returns correct results: typeof TouchEvent != "undefined" shows Yes, other tests show No. (I run tests at [http://modernizr.github.com/Modernizr/touch.html](http://modernizr.github.com/Modernizr/touch.html))

Comment: hmm.. I have Version 23.0.1271.97 m and typeof TouchEvent != "undefined" is the only one showing Yes.  Are you running Win 8 RTM (or a Consumer Preview?)

Comment: @JimO'Neil thank you for your replies. I'm running Win 8 via VMware Fusion on Mac Pro. It's not a Consumer Preview. It doesn't seem to be RTM either. Basic info about my comp (Control Panel > System) shows: Win version: Windows 8, Pen and Touch: Limited touch support with 8 touch points. Does it clarify anything?