# Prevent hyperlink on touch and show hover state

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, mobile-safari

I'm not sure why but when I touch a link on on a site I'm building on an iPhone/tablet it doesn't trigger the hover over state and instead just jumps straight through to the link. You can see the test site here http://lovelldesign.co.uk/home

The links are just big images and the hover over state reveals the name of the project, that's why it's essential that the hover over state is triggered by the first touch and then the user would need to touch again to go through to the project.

I've searched for touchstart examples on here and tried to work from them to solve my own problem but to no avail.

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="projectContainer">
    <a href="<perch:content id="url" label="URL" required="true" />" class="projectOverlay">
        <h1><perch:content id="title" type="text" label="Heading" required="true" /></h1>
    </a> 
    <img src="<perch:content id="image" type="image" label="image" />" />
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.projectContainer {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    height: 100%;
    display: block; }

.projectContainer:hover .projectOverlay {
    opacity: 0.9;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out; }

.projectContainer .projectOverlay {
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: #00152e;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 96%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 2%;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none; }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: On touch-based devices, touch is equivalent to click, there is no `:hover`.

Comment: Note this is not an answer but you might find that jQuery touchpunch library may help you as it wires things up auto for you for many scenarios. Meaning it may not resolve this issue but probably will others for you in the future. something for you to consider and investigate.

Comment: There no :hover but there is a css value at least in safari there is -webkit-tap-highlight-color: which might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same "issue" (actually it's the correct behaviour) sometimes. To fix it, you need a little of javascript.

First of all, let's detect touch events. You can do it with Modernizr, this is the minimum bundle to achieve it:
http://modernizr.com/download/#-touch-cssclasses-teststyles-prefixes

1) include the generated script in your `<head>` section: Modernizr is going to add a "**touch**" class to your page's `<html>` element if touch events are supported, a "**no-touch**" class if they're not.

2) if "touch" events are enabled, we need to add a javascript listener to simulate the hover state at first click:

```
if(Modernizr.touch){

    var hoverClass = 'projectContainer-hover', // the "simulated hover" class
        $projectContainers = $('.projectContainer');

    $projectContainers.on('click',function(event){
        var $this = $(this);
        if(!$this.hasClass(hoverClass)){
            event.preventDefault();
            $projectContainers.removeClass(hoverClass);
            $this.addClass(hoverClass);
            return false;
        }
    }).on('focusout',function(){
        // remove the class if the user focuses on another element
        $(this).removeClass(hoverClass);  
    });
}
```

I'm supposing you're using jQuery. If you're not, and you need to support older IEs, you should know that selecting elements by their class [is not easy](http://code.google.com/p/getelementsbyclassname/).

3) At last, change your css selector this way:

```
.projectContainer:hover .projectOverlay, .projectContainer-hover .projectOverlay {
    // ...etc...    
}
```

---

**NOTE**: this method isn't perfect at all, because touch events are enabled in many laptops too nowadays. Any device with touch events enabled will need a double click if you implement it. It's up to you to decide if it's worth it!

Atm i think the only alternative is user-agent spoofing, which you ***really want to avoid***.

Comment: Ah that's great thank you so much @Giona works great. I've only come across one issue. If you touch one project so the hover appears, then touch another so previous hover disappears and new one appears, and then go back to touch the first project instead of the hover over appearing it goes straight through to the link. Do you know if there's a way I can reset it after each touch? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yup, seen the problem on iPad & iPhone... check my edit, it should work now ;-)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks @Giona Works Perfectly now, I've updated the files online so people can see it working [lovelldesign.co.uk](http://lovelldesign.co.uk/home). Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Glad to help ;-) ciao @tobias_burkill

Comment: Note that the 'touch' class added by Modernizr only shows that the *browser* supports touch interaction - not necessarily that the _device_ supports it. This can cause issues - see for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934987/chrome-browser-on-windows-8-desktop-touch-support-error